# laravel in google compute engine - permission denied for log files

Tags: apache, laravel-4, google-compute-engine

I am trying to install a laravel project in google compute engine with "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7".

I followed this blog: http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-centos/

Completed the laravel project download, set up user permission for user "apache" and group "apache". After all this, I am getting error as

```
Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/var/www/html/project/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/project/bootstrap/compiled.php:9072
```

Who ever had the problem earlier, mentions the solution as set proper permission for the log files. I have verified that app/storage folder has correct permissions.

I know I am missing something very simple, but could not get this working.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
These are the permissions I have applied:

```
chown -R apache:apache project
chmod 775 project
chmod 775 project/app/storage
chmod -R 777 project/app/storage
```

And these are the permissions I can see for the folder:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 7 apache apache 4096 Dec 23 13:54
drwxrwxr-x. 7 apache apache   84 Dec 23 13:53 storage
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 0 Dec 23 14:01 laravel.log
```

Comment: This is definitely a permission issue. Not to beat the same drum over and over again, but have you applied the permission recursively and made sure that the file exists? Also what level of permission have you applied to it?

Comment: updated my question with the settings i did for the folders and permissions I can see for the folders/files.

Comment: see if this helps, first do `php artisan cache:clear` then set recursive 777 permission, then `php artisan dump-autoload`. If this works, please let me know so I can post this as an answer.

Comment: I have to tried that one as well earlier, but with no luck :( Could there be any issue with RHEL 7?

Comment: Red Hat should follow the same levels and commands. Can you set the permission for all users and not just apache.apache?

Comment: sudo chmod -R a+rw /var/www/html/project I applied these permissions but still getting same error :(

Comment: Okay I have one more try, have you done a chown on the folders? this would allow you to set permission for that user. usually apache or www-data.

Comment: try your www-data. ususally username:www-data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67561/discussion-between-saravanan-s-and-ykbks).

Answer (score 1):

Not able to figure out if this is an issue with RHEL linux 7 issue. I gave up on this after a while and created a VM with centOS 6 which is now working properly. Thanks a lot @ykbks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to disable SELinux.

```
~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/selinux
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted

# SETLOCALDEFS= Check local definition changes
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

Changing the value of SELINUX to **disabled** changes the state of SELinux and the name of the policy to be used the next time the system boots.